# In PySide6, why assignment before super().__init__() might lead to abnormal result?

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization, pyside

Class A is derived from QObject, and class B is derived from A. In the GUI, when the OK button is clicked, the method `B.log()` is invoked, and it prints 'Hi' in the console. Here is the code:

main.py

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QTimer, QUrl, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QmlElement, QQmlApplicationEngine

QML_IMPORT_NAME = 'PyLib'
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1


class A(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


@QmlElement
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @Slot()
    def log(self):
        print('Hi')


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QUrl('main.qml'))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import PyLib

ApplicationWindow {
    height: 100
    width: 100
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "OK"
        onClicked: b.log()
    }

    B {
        id: b
    }
}
```

Then I find something I cannot explain:

1. If I set an instance variable to a QTimer object before `super().__init__()` in the `__init__()` method of class B, i.e.,

```
@QmlElement
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = QTimer()
        super().__init__()

    @Slot()
    def log(self):
        print('Hi')
```

when the OK button is clicked, no 'Hi' is printed. However, if I set the instance variable to an int or a string, e.g.,

```
@QmlElement
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = 1
        super().__init__()

    @Slot()
    def log(self):
        print('Hi')
```

when the OK button is clicked, 'Hi' is printed.

2. If a QTimer object is assigned to a local variable instead of an instance variable, i.e.,

```
@QmlElement
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        t = QTimer()
        super().__init__()

    @Slot()
    def log(self):
        print('Hi')
```

the GUI window won't be shown.

It seems `super().__init__()` must be called first in the initialization method, otherwise it might lead to abnormal result. Is that true?

Comment: Seems like a bug, but keep in mind that QObjects are complex objects also due to the fact that they are wrapped in a python object. Python bindings have to make some complex operations "under the hood" whenever a QObject is initialized. As a rule of thumb, the `__init__` should always be called at the very beginning, and before creating further QObjects that may be part of it. Still, the fact that this happens also without making the timer an instance member puzzles me (as said, it could be a bug).

Comment: The equivalent PyQt5/PyQt6 example works as expected, but the same bug is present in both PySide2 and PySide6.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. Yes, I agree the ```__init__``` should always be called at the very beginning. Actually I met this problem because I passed a QObject as an argument into ```super().__init__()``` which was at the very beginning, i.e., ```super().__init__(QTimer())```, and the slot method could not be invoked.

Comment: @Isaac Wait. In your question there's no reference to attempts to call `super()` like that. If you *actually* tried to do `super().__init__(QTimer(<…>))`, then: 1. that is **just wrong**; 2. we cannot answer questions if the provided code doesn't reflect the real problem. Calling the base `__init__` at the very beginning is not absolute rule, it's something that should be carefully considered. Still, if you called it with an object created on the fly (as per your comment), then *that* is a serious problem, most importantly due to the persistence of that object. Did you provide a *valid* [mre]?

Comment: @musicamante Sorry for my confusing description. At first, I tried to do ```super().__init__(QTimer())``` and set the newly constructed QTimer object to an instance variable in the base class. Then I met the problem and could not explain it. So I made several attempts to find the cause. One attempt was creating the QTimer object before passing into the base ```__init__```, the problem didn't vanish. And then I found even creating the QTimer object before the base ```__init__``` without passing into it, the problem was still there. And this attempt led to the question I asked in this post.

Comment: @musicamante I think the code in the post is a valid minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Isaac Ok, thanks for the clarification (sorry, but it's necessary to ask in these cases). As hinted in my first comment (and confirmed by [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842442/in-pyside6-why-assignment-before-super-init-might-lead-to-abnormal-resu?noredirect=1#comment135470042_76842442)), it's probably a bug. Be aware, though: your approach cannot be considered "strictly conventional", especially considering the aspects related to Python/C++ bindings. Still, I believe it *is* a bug, so I suggest you to file a report on https://bugreports.qt.io using the PYSIDE tag.